# Dojo - how to use editable grid with dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dojo

Can anyone please suggest me how do I use editable grid with dojox.grid.enhancedGrid. Is it possible for edit mode of Textbox by default ? Also, Suggest me how do I read the complete set of grid data into a JSON ?

Comment: Hi! You can set the cells of the Datagrid editable:true, so you can change it's content. For exporting the grid, use the Plugin Exporter.

Comment: Thanks. Will the editable text box value will populate ?

Comment: What do you mean? You can setup a Textbox inside of the grid and you can write a value in it.

Comment: Yes, Will I able to retrieve the textbox value in the plugin exporter ?

Comment: I guess it will be exported as a normal Cellvalue

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have migerated to dgrid framework. Its easy and I can get all the data from grid.store.data and grid.save() methods